# Why does iOS code error in uploading App to App Store?

Tags: ios

My app was rejected by Apple.  Please see the attached screenshot.

Can you suggest how I can resolve this?

> We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect. Specifically, the app does not use the in-app permissions alert and instead thats the user to Settings in order to allow permissions.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to address all instances of this type of issue.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be accessing restricted areas of the API (contacts/location/notifications/etc) without first prompting the user through one of the supplied "authenticate" methods (and supplying a reason)

Comment: Your app should simply try and access the camera, which will trigger the standard permissions dialog from iOS.  You are presenting your own dialog that directs the user to settings.  This is not very user friendly

Comment: you need to give camera access. Just add this code to info.plist <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} library Usage</string>

Comment: Show this dialog if user previously deny camera permission

Comment: @Manohar Chowdary, this rejection comes under app completeness. you are showing an alert when app tries to access camera or photo library. but the content you are showing is not conveying what the app does with that. so edit your content properly.